# How to bring to front a programmatically generated UILabel in a UITableView, in Swift

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a programmatically generated UITableView with many UILabel's.
Each added UILabel should be seen in front.
All works ok until I add the final UILabel, which appears behind all the others.

How can I bring it to the front?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        if( dbg )   NSLog( @"       - cell nil");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
        /* Though it's UITableViewCellStyleDefault, the three defaults (image, label, detail label) are nil
                if not set. */


        // UI controls must be preset for re-used, to prevent memory leak:

        // Allocate max. possible UI controls for this row, once per boot:
        int instance;
        for(  instance=0; instance < MAX_CELL_UILABEL; ++instance )
        {
            UILabel*   cell_UILabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];  // allocate next UI control
            [cell.contentView addSubview: cell_UILabel ];                           // add it permanently to the cell
            cell_UILabel.tag = BASE_UILABEL_TAG + instance;                         // assign unique ID for later lookup
        }
```

...

OTHER UILABELS ARE ADDED HERE.

AND, HERE IS THE FINAL UILABEL, WHICH APPEARS BEHIND THE REST, WHEN IT *SHOULD* APPEAR IN FRONT:

```
UILabel*   battery_percent = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG + ul++];
battery_percent.frame = CGRectMake  (x,y, w,h);
battery_percent.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
battery_percent.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; // NSTextAlignmentRight, NSTextAlignmentLeft
battery_percent.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: font_size];
battery_percent.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
battery_percent.numberOfLines=0;

// Show battery %:
battery_percent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d%%", battery_charge_percent ];
```

Comment: Your post is muddy and unclear. Some of your post is in code tags, and some is not, making it all but impossible to read. You have "if (cell == 0) code shown without showing the code that tries to dequeue a cell. You don't show the code that adds all the fields to the cell, and you don't explain your tagging system, what an "instance" is, or what your "ul" variable does. Your "battery_percent" label code fetches an existing label with a tag number, but because your code is incomplete, we can't tell how that particular field is created. Please post your entire CellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer elsewhere on Stackoverflow:

[cell.contentView   bringSubviewToFront:   battery_percent];

Sweet!

Answer (score 6):

```
[cell bringSubviewToFront:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

From

```
int instance;
for(  instance=0; instance < MAX_CELL_UILABEL; ++instance )
{
    UILabel*   cell_UILabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];  // allocate next UI control
    [cell.contentView addSubview: cell_UILabel ];                           // add it permanently to the cell
    cell_UILabel.tag = BASE_UILABEL_TAG + instance;                         // assign unique ID for later lookup
}
```

The **battery_percent** label should have a **tag** value of (BASE_UILABEL_TAG + MAX_CELL_UILABEL - 1)

When you grab the **battery_percent** label later on with

```
UILabel*   battery_percent = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG + ul++];
```

What is the value of **ul** at this point?

If it isn't equivalent to (MAX_CELL_UILABEL - 1) then you're grabbing the wrong label.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am not sure where you are adding the `battery_percent` label...either `cell` or `cell.contentView`
So I would suggest you to Use this.

```
[[battery_percent superView] bringSubviewToFront:battery_percent];
```

**Hope this will help you.**